# Embedded Flash application, editable TextFields are not selectable when added as a children of source in fl.controls.ScrollPane

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, embed, mouseevent

I have a flash app using `fl.controls.ScrollPane` as a container for a `Sprite` form.
The `ScrollPane.source` is referenced to the `Sprite` form with `flash.text.TextField` as some of the form's children.

I tested using Firefox and Chrome browsers.

When the flash file is called directly from the development server, the flash application runs  correctly, except for the fact that one needs to click **twice** before being able to select the editable `TextField`.

The situation worsens when the flash is embedded on a page with strict control attributes such as:

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
src="https://localhost:flashfile.swf" width="400" height="300"
quality="high" scale="scale" allowfullscreen="true"
allowscriptaccess="never" salign="tl" wmode="opaque">
```

I read that `wmode=opaque` can bring some undesirable side effects, but it is ridiculous, that I **can't even select** the `TextField` objects. Event the mouse scroll isn't captured anymore. The mouse events are not hitting the `TextField` objects.

This is a peculiar case because other objects such as `fl.controls.CheckBox` and `fl.controls.ComboBox` works, as they still are clickable/selectable.

**Question**: Is there something I should know about in this special scenario of `ScrollPane` and embedding using `wmode=opaque` that I'm missing out here?

Answer (score 1):

After searching the web for half a day, and combing the AS3 documentation till my eyes go blind, I finally found a hint to a solution to my problem. I'm just doing a brain dump here to fix the `TextField` selection issue.

A lot of search results hinted at the problems of `wmode=opaque` and how browsers control the mouse events, but not many turn up direct answers or solutions.

http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=170310

The forum question above gives a hint, that the `ScrollPane` object, actually captures the first mouse click for focus, then lets the subsequent click go through to the children object. The tip given is as shown:

```
myScrollPane.focusEnabled = false
```

setting `focusEnabled` property to `false`.

For completeness, I've explicitly set more properties just to be sure:

```
mouseFocusEnabled = false; // disable mouse focus on the scrollpane
focusEnabled = false; // disable focus on the scrollpane
mouseEabled = true; // receives mouse input
mouseChildren = true; // enable for selecting children objects
```

Miraculously, my clicks are able to select the editable `TextField` objects when the flash is embedded using the `wmode=opaque` (I'm still not actually sure whether this is the issue).

The mouse scroll events however, seems to be only solvable with external javascript. There's no internal AS3 solutions.

That said, the unanswered question is: I'm still not sure where or how web browsers capture the mouse events then selectively pass them into the embedded flash containers. If someone can shed light on this, and also point to some solution, that would be great.